# How to Union the List<T> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am having a two List instances namely OldCustomers, NewCustomers.

```
List<Customer> OldCustomers;

List<Customer> NewCustomers;
```

I just want the Union of both Oldcustomers, NewCustomers. That is if the CustomerID 100 is present in the OldCustomerList and also in the NewCustomer List then the Customer Details in the OldCustomer List has to be Removed and the NewCustomer List has to be placed in the Resulting List as like below.

```
List<Customer> NewCustomers;
    Union
List<Customer> OldCustomers;
```

how do i Do that in LINQ?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have you tried the `Union` method? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Union`, you have to customize `EqualityComparer`:

```
public class CusComparer : EqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public override bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        return x.CustomerID == y.CustomerID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return obj.CustomerId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var unionCustomers = NewCustomers.Union(OldCustomers, new CusComparer());
```

Comment: You need to call `GetHashCode` on the `CustomerID` rather than on `obj`, as `GetHashCode` is checked for equality before `Equals` is checked.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: don't assume, try this

Answer (score 0):

you can use union function like this

```
sequence1.Union(sequence2)
```

i.e.

```
var custlist =  NewCustomers.Union(OldCustomers).ToList();
```

Read : [Enumerable.Union Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

Example :

```
            int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
            int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

            IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

            foreach (int num in union)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", num);
            }

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             5 3 9 7 8 6 4 1 0
            */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) like

```
var union = NewCustomers.Union(OldCustomers);
```

And probably you will have to implement your own [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb358407%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your `Customer` class

Answer (score 0):

`Union` will compare the instances of Customer object(if `IEqualityComparer` is not used). I think you are looking for something like `UnionBy`

```
var finalList = NewCustomers.Concat(OldCustomers)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID)
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .ToList();
```

--EDIT--

A possible `UnionBy` implementation:

```
var finalList = NewCustomers.UnionBy(OldCustomers, c => c.CustomerID).ToList();
```

-

```
public static class SOExtension
{

    public static IEnumerable<T> UnionBy<T,V>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> otherList,Func<T,V> selector)
    {
        HashSet<V> set = new HashSet<V>();

        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            set.Add(selector(t));
            yield return t;
        }
        foreach(T t in otherList)
        {
            if(!set.Contains(selector(t)))
                yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to take all new customers and all old customers which are not in the new list:

```
List<Customer> customers = NewCustomers.Concat(OldCustomers.Except(NewCustomers)).ToList();
```

Remember to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic interface to compare your customers(probably by `CustomerID`). Therefore you need to provide your own `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for `Customer`.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        Customer cust = obj as Customer;
        if (cust == null) return false;
        return cust.CustomerID == CustomerID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CustomerID.GetHashCode();
    }

    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
    {
        public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null) return true;
            if (x == null || y == null) return false;
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return -1;
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that i override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Customer`. On this way you don't even need to pass an instance of the `IEqualityComparer<Customer>` to `Except`(or any other method which allows to pass a comparer).

But for the sake of completeness i've also added the class `Comparer` which implements the interface, so you can also pass it to Except:

```
NewCustomers.Concat(OldCustomers.Except(NewCustomers, new Customer.Comparer()));
```

Comment: As you commented: `Works only correctly if GetHashCode and Equals was implemented properly`

Comment: Edited to provide a possible implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: If you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in Customer class, you don't need to customize EqualityComparer, it will use EqualityComparer<Customer>.Default

Comment: @CuongLe: Similar to what i've mentioned at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<Customer> set = new HashSet<Customer>(list1);
set.SymmectricExceptWith(list2); // Or other userful methods.
```